# Parametirized queries with the same query hash but different plan. Only change is comments

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Observation:
I am running a parameterized query from a .Net app using ADO .net. Using the DMvs I extracted the query hash of the query. Now I added 1 line comment to the query and re-ran. What I have observed is even though the **query hash is the same**, they create **2 different plans** in the plan cache. Below is the code:

```
SELECT 
[DEQS].[creation_time],
[DEQS].[last_execution_time],
[DEQS].[execution_count],
[DEQS].[query_hash],
[DEQS].[query_plan_hash],
[DEQS].[plan_handle],
[DEST].[text] FROM
[sys].[dm_exec_query_stats] AS [DEQS]
CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text]([DEQS].[sql_handle]) AS [DEST] WHERE
[DEQS].[query_hash] = 0x0434D807E082C759
```

Question:
Why is this the case? As per the book, *SQL Server Execution Plans By Grant Fritchey* optimizer looks at the query hash has to determine if optimization is needed. [Attached is a screenshot from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrRN9.png)